# Why is there n-1 different objects in a n by n matrix game like Bejeweled?

Tags: matrix, grid, logic

For games that consists of a grid, and is similar to the concept like bejeweled: has an n by n matrix and n-1 different objects.

What is the reason for this? Why not have more than n-1 different objects, or have less than n-1 objects. What is the logic behind this?

Some Examples:

DOTS have a 6 by 6 matrix, with 5 different colors of circles

Bejeweled has a 8 by 8 matrix with 7 different jewels

ANIPANG has a 7 by 7 matrix with 6 different animals[image]

[image: DOTS have a 6 by 6 matrix, with 5 different colors of circles]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I created this app to easily test how many auto-completes will be in a bejeweled like game based on a random start.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/row-test/4759793086627840

I think that having less than N-1 objects would result in way to many auto-completes, which would make the game not challenging, but having N objects very rarely results in any auto-completes at all. I will continue working on the app until I have a functioning game of bejeweled that was an "AI" which tries to switch random tiles, and we will see how far the "AI" gets with different conditions.